# What is the probability that Ramona catches her bus on Monday, Tuesday and Thursday, but misses it on Wednesday and Friday?

Tags: probability

Problem statement -

Every morning Ramona misses her bus with probability $\frac {1}{10}$, independently of other mornings. What is the probability that next week she catches her bus on Monday, Tuesday and Thursday, but misses her bus on Wednesday and Friday?

My attempt -

M = {catches bus on Monday}

T = {catches bus on Tuesday}

TR = {catches bus on Thursday}

$W^C$ = {misses bus on Wednesday}

$F^C$ = {misses bus on Friday}

We want to find P(M $\bigcap$ T $\bigcap$ TR $\bigcap$ $W^C$ $\bigcap$ $F^C$). We know all of these events are independent with respect to one another. Thus,

P(M $\bigcap$ T $\bigcap$ TR $\bigcap$ $W^C$ $\bigcap$ $F^C$) = P(M)P(T)P(TR)P($W^C$)P($F^C$)

Which equals $\frac{9^3}{10^3}$$\frac{1}{10^2}$. This simplifies to $\frac{729}{100000}$. I looked at the back of the book to check my answer, and it answer it had was $\frac{729}{10000}$.

**Is the book's answer incorrect? If not, then what did I do wrong?**

Comment: You answer looks solid, I assume the book has a typo.

Answer (score 2):

The other poster's answer is incorrect as well as the textbook. It is a given that the events are pairwise independent. Thus, we can readily calculate the answer by computing $P(M) * P(Tu) * P(W^c) * P(Th) * P(F^c) = 9/10 * 9/10 * 1/10 * 9/10 * 1/10 = \dfrac{729}{10^5}$, where $P(day)$ is the probability that Ramona DOES catch her bus on that day.

EDIT: This follows from the fact that if a collection of events are independent, then the probability of their intersection is equal to the product of the individual probabilities, which is included in that chapter of the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is almost correct.

The book answer is also wrong (probably a typo).

Your answer is a solution another problem: *What is the probability of riding 3 days of the week and not riding 2 days of the week?*

But the problem asks for a specific *choice* of days, mainly ride M, T, and Th and not ride W and F.

This means that we need to consider **which days** and therefore use **combinations** as well! *Note: we do not use **permutations** because the order of the days of the week is **fixed**. In other words, we do not want to count these as separate choices:

1. Ride **M T Th**, not ride **W F**
2. Ride **M Th T**, not ride **W F**
3. Ride **T Th M**, not ride **W F**
4. Ride **T M Th**, not ride **W F**
5. Ride **Th T M**, not ride **W F**
6. Ride **Th M T**, not ride **W F**

Rather, we want to count all of these choices permutations as *1 choice*! Therefore, we use **combinations**.

So to find the permutations, we need to *choose* 3 out of 5 days to ride the bus: $$\frac{5!}{\left(5-3\right)!3!} = \textbf{10 ways}$$

We can choose 3 days out of 5 to ride the bus. *Note: this implies that we are also choosing 2 days where we do not ride the bus.*

Therefore, we want only 1 out of 10 ways we can pick 3 days to ride the bus in a week. So, we must divide by the number of ways, or multiply by 1/10.

Therefore, the answer is **$$\frac{1}{10} * \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^3 * \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2 = \frac{729}{1000000}$$**

Intuition: We need to consider the number of ways we can ride 3 days a week, otherwise, our probability includes possibilities out of the scope of the problem. For example, only considering the probabilities and not the number of combinations. An answer of $$\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^3 * \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2$$ would include valid sequences:

Ride **M T W**, not ride **Th, F**

Ride **W Th F**, not ride **M, T**

etc...

We can clearly see why ignoring the choices we have — when we want to pick 3 days to ride and 2 days to not ride — is problematic! Therefore, we must also consider the number of possibilities (i.e. combinations in this case)!

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  You forgot to multiply by the $10$ ways she could catch the bus on three of the five days.